# Spring - Request context or Security context for store only the access token?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a RESTFul API that needs to receive **only the AcessToken** and validate if the requested action is allowed validating the token.

As I will only receive(as extra value) the AcessToken, is better to store the token in **Request context** or in **Security context**?

**Is performatic start the security context just for use access token?**

Thanks for atention!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not problematic to use the security context for security related tasks.  If anything, it's preferred to use it because that's what it's intended for.

Whether you should use it depends on your specific situation.  For instance, if you are implementing basic security for Rest API that protects a little used system that is unlikely to be extended to multiple users or need additional security mechanisms added, I would say use a simple filter to look for the token and use the **Request Context** (By which I assume you mean storing the token in the request for the life of the request)

If, on the other hand, this is a production system with multiple users that may need to scale and be expendable, by all means, use Spring Security and use the **Security Context**.  Spring Security can be difficult to use if you haven't used it before, but will be better in the long run because you're following a well documented standard instead of just making something that works.

Comment: Houp... I agree!!! Do u know how I treat the authentication manager once I have a stateless API?

Comment: This is an article I used when I set it up before.  Proved helpful http://technicalrex.com/2015/02/20/stateless-authentication-with-spring-security-and-jwt